# Error running R script. unable to find an inherited method for function ‘seqnames’ for signature ‘"NULL"

Tags: r

I'm running a script to compute MAD scores from DNA sequencing data. The following is my bash script:

```
Project_dir=~/base
cd /${Project_dir}
SCRTP=~/scRepliseq-Pipeline
rscript=~/scRepliseq-Pipeline/util/Step4_R_MAD_score.R
in_dir="Aneu_analysis/bins"
out_dir="Aneu_analysis/MAD_score"
out_name="F121_MAD_scores.txt"
Rscript --vanilla $rscript $in_dir $out_dir $out_name
```

This then runs a bioconductor package "AneuFinder" in R using the following R script:

```
library(AneuFinder)

options(scipen=100)
args = commandArgs(TRUE)
in_dir=args[1]
out_dir=args[2]
out_name=args[3]

files=list.files(in_dir,pattern=".Rdata",full.names=T)

out=NULL
for (file in files){
load(file) #bin file

#200k bins data
data=data.frame(chr=seqnames(bins_reads$`200000`),
                starts=start(bins_reads$`200000`)-1,
                ends=end(bins_reads$`200000`),
                elementMetadata(bins_reads$`200000`)$counts)

rmZero=data[,4] !=0
data_rmZero=data[rmZero,]
med=median(data_rmZero[,4])
med_scaled=data_rmZero[,4]/med
MAD=mad(med_scaled)
MAD_log=mad(log2(med_scaled))

name=basename(file)

out=rbind(out,c(name,MAD_log))
}

colnames(out)=c("Name","MAD_score_log2")

write.table(out,paste0(out_dir,"/",out_name,"_MAD_scores_log2.txt"),sep="\t",row.names=F,col.namol.names=T,quote=F)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘seqnames’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
Calls: data.frame -> seqnames -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I've tested all the arguments and they run fine, so my thoughts are that there is a problem with the data file (as suggested by the error). Below, I include `head()` of the data file:

```
$`binsize_2e+05`
GRanges object with 13161 ranges and 3 metadata columns:
          seqnames              ranges strand |    counts   mcounts   pcounts
             <Rle>           <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer> <integer> <integer>
      [1]     chr1            1-200000      * |         0         0         0
      [2]     chr1       200001-400000      * |         0         0         0
      [3]     chr1       400001-600000      * |         0         0         0
      [4]     chr1       600001-800000      * |         0         0         0
      [5]     chr1      800001-1000000      * |         0         0         0
      ...      ...                 ...    ... .       ...       ...       ...
  [13157]     chrX 170000001-170200000      * |        11         3         8
  [13158]     chrX 170200001-170400000      * |         0         0         0
  [13159]     chrX 170400001-170600000      * |         0         0         0
  [13160]     chrX 170600001-170800000      * |         1         0         1
  [13161]     chrX 170800001-171000000      * |         0         0         0
```

I'm a novice so sorry if the answer is obvious. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which line throws the error?  What are the current values of the objects referenced in that line?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I included a trackback to log the error:
`Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Name", "MAD_score_log2")) :
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
Calls: colnames<- -> colnames<-
4: (function ()
   traceback(2))()
3: stop("attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions")
2: `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Name", "MAD_score_log2"))
1: `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Name", "MAD_score_log2"))`

Comment: OK.  That suggests `out` is `NULL`.  Is it? If so, why?

Comment: Yes out is NULL. However, if this line is removed I still get the same error. I thought that the error was in the dataframe under seqnames but i cant see anything wrong with that column

Comment: So work through the code, line by line, to see where things start to go wrong.  You haven't given us any reproducible data, so you're on your own, I suspect.